# Putting uncompressed json file into resources?

Tags: android, apk, android-resources

I have uncompressed json file and I want to have it in resources. Should I compress it, or it is compressed when I will make an apk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be compressed in apk, so you need not to compress it yourself